# Loop-carried dependency. Detection

Tags: x86

```
mov ebx, beginOfArray
xor eax, eax
.L:
    movsd xmm3, [ebx]
    mulsd xmm3, xmm1
    mulsd xmm1, xmm2
    addsd xmm0, xmm3 
    add   eax, 8
    cmp eax, 1024
    jl .L
```

And for my eye loop-carried dependency:

```
add eax, 8 
mulsd xmm1, xmm2
addsd xmm0, xmm3
```

So we have three loop-carried dependecy.
But, I am not sure why the `mulsd xmm3, xmm1` is not dependency. Why? `xmm3` is not a problem in fact ( Register renaming) but, after all, this instruction have to wait till `mulsd xmm1, xmm2` will be finished from previous iteration. So, why it is not a dependency loop-carried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmm3 is the result of a load that depends only on the loop counter, so it's not part of a long loop-carried dep chain.  The `mulsd xmm3,xmm1` "forks" a new dep chain every iteration.

Every iteration has a separate load->mulsd chain to produce an input for addsd.

`addsd xmm0, xmm3` is a 3-cycle loop-carried dep chain, but parallelism is possible in computing the xmm3 source operand for each iteration.